Access this in a function which is a property of an object
the title may not be clear, so here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve :
const myObj = {
  propA: 'foo',
  propFunc: (arg) => arg + this.propA
}

Basaically, my object has a function as one of its properties, and I want that function to be able to access other properties of the object.
I want to do it like this so I can dynamically change the value or propA and have propFunc access the new value once called.
And so I can define new variables like so, simply overriding propA, and not having to redefine propFunc :
const myObj2 = {...myObj, propA: 'bar' };

Predictably, the compiler is not happy on my use of this.
Is it possible to do it or not? Thanks

Arrow functions do not have their own this context, they inherit the this value from the enclosing scope.
You can try this:
const myObj = {
  propA: 'foo',
  propFunc: function(arg) {
    return arg + this.propA;
  }
}

or the shorthand :

const myObj = {
  propA: 'foo',
  propFunc(arg) {
    return arg + this.propA;
  }
}

console.log(myObj.propFunc('hello')); // Output: "hellofoo"

const myObj2 = {...myObj, propA: 'bar' };

console.log(myObj2.propFunc('hello')); // Output: "hellobar"


I know arrow functions don't have access to this, and I knew that was the problem, but somehow, my brain didn't think of using the function syntax, it's friday. It seems the shorthand propA(arg) {return arg + this.propA;} also works. Thanks
